# Graphicsmagick not working in cmd, but works in webstorm

Tags: gruntjs, graphicsmagick

I have an interesting issue with Graphicsmagick. I've installed grunt-responsive-images-converter, and successfully configure it. The problem is that it works only when I run it form Webstorm IDE, but when I run it in cmd I get this error:

> Running "responsive_images:resize" (responsive_images) task
>
> spawn ENOENT
>   Warning:
>   Please ensure GraphicsMagick is installed correctly.
>   `brew install graphicsmagick` or see http://www.graphicsmagick.org/download.html for more > > details.
>   Alternatively, set options.engine to 'im' to use ImageMagick.
>   Use --force to continue.

I've installed GraphicsMagick-1.3.19-Q16-win64-dll.exe with checked checkbox:"Update executable search path".

I don't know what can I do more, so please help :)

Comment: Got the same here. Did you solve this ?